# How to force table width 100% to parent form element in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

Form contains table element whose widt is mared as 100% :

```
<form class="browse-addtocart-form" method="post">
  <table class="productTable ui-corner-all" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
 ....
```

In latest FireFox, table width is too big. left side is outside of form.
In IE10 and Chrome table width is 100% to form.

In FireFox table width is too big, it is rendered wider than gray area.
In Chrome and IE10 page is rendered properly.

How to render proper width in fireFox also ?

jquery, jquery-ui are used.

Comment: That happens because the form has 100% width despite having an element on his left, and the table is using that 100% width as well, but since the table behaves as a box, it's stretching out. Have you tried working with the form CSS?

Comment: I removed width='100%' from table. It looks like this solves the issue.

Comment: Don't forget to check on other browsers if there's no problem with that solution.

Comment: removing width='100%' makes table too narrow. How to force table to be bigger so that there is more white space in every column?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could also apply a style to the form itself:

```
clear: both;
```

Comment: This creates narrow table, column width are exactly as column header widths and there is no white space between column headers. How to make table wider so that there is some white space between columns ? width='100%' creates such table.

Comment: `clear:both` does not resolve the issue. Table is still in same place. Adding `<br/>` before table moves table to new row so that it starts from left side. Will this work with all text and image sizes ?